# MySQLCommand StoredProcedure has some cache in definition

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have a method that calls a Stored Procedure in MySQL database:

```
public DataTable ExecuteSP_ReturnDataTable(DynamicGridAction pAction)
        {
            DataTable ret = new DataTable();
            MySqlCommand wCmd = new MySqlCommand();

            try
            {
                wCmd = new MySqlCommand(pAction.SPName);
                wCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                
                wCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(pAction.SPParameterName, MySqlDbType.LongText)).Value = pAction.SPParameterViewColumn;

                MySqlParameter outMessage = new MySqlParameter("pmessage", MySqlDbType.LongText);
                outMessage.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                wCmd.Parameters.Add(outMessage);

                if (base.mSqlTransaction == null)
                    wCmd.Connection = base.GetOpenedConection();
                else
                {
                    wCmd.Connection = (MySqlConnection)base.mSqlTransaction.Connection;
                    wCmd.Transaction = (MySqlTransaction)base.mSqlTransaction;
                }
                ret.Load(wCmd.ExecuteReader());

                return ret;
            }
            catch (MySqlException exp)
            {
                throw new FunctionalException(exp.Number, exp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                if (base.mSqlTransaction == null)
                    base.CloseConection();
            }
        }
```

The StoredProcedure name and Parameter name are dinamics.

When I execute that method at the first time, it works. After that, I changed the name of the storedprocedure parameter in mysql (newParamName), and I change the "pAction.SPParameterName" value with the same (newParamName).

I execute that method after that and, surprisingly, the wCmd.ExecuteReader() method throws me:
System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter 'oldParamName' not found in the collection.'

I debug the code step by step and the name of the parameter is correct (the new one), but i get that exception every time I call that method.
But, if I restart the application (.net6 webapi), it works.

I think that there is some kind of "cache" for the StoredProcedure definition in my aplication.

The problem is that I need to change the parameter's name (I took it from other table in database), but the method continue internally calling the old one until I restart the aplication.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `pAction.SPParameterName` how do you change this? is it in the code? do you build and deploy your application after the code change?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is I need to change dinamically the parameter's name, but the command calls the old defintiion with the old parameter name.
I changed the pAction.SPParameterName value outside that method. (I read it from database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySql.Data, set `Procedure Cache Size = 0;` in your connection string.

From [Connection Options Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html):

> `ProcedureCacheSize`, `Procedure Cache Size`, `procedure cache`, `procedurecache`
>
> Default: 25
>
> Sets the size of the stored procedure cache. By default, Connector/NET stores the metadata (input/output data types) about the last 25 stored procedures used. To disable the stored procedure cache, set the value to zero (0).